# What will be the capacitance of a Multiple Plate Capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

I have a question about parallel plate capacitor

If a capacitor has $n$ number of plates, will its capacitance be combination of series or parallel?

for e.g. let $n=3$

- ----| | |----- + this is how capacitor will look

Comment: Its series or just one C with larger distance of plates

Answer (score 0):

With capacitors in series, the (q's) must be equal and the voltages add: q/$C_1$ + q/$C_2$ …. = q/$C_E$.